# PouchDB Not Working on HTC Device

Tags: android, cordova, pouchdb, htc-android

I've creating an phonegap android app using PouchDB.

Here is list of devices that i've tested:
 - HTC One Mini - not worked
 - HTC Desire X - not worked
 - Lenovo A690 - worked fine
 - LG G2 - worked fine
 - Emulator Android (4.0.0 - 4.2.2) - worked fine

I figured out only HTC Device not worked as well as other device. I've tested on my HTC one mini default browser, and it didn't work out. But it worked fine when i test on my HTC One mini Google Chrome browser.

You can see my code on : 
[PouchDB on Phonegap (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541302/pouchdb-on-phonegap-android)

Any solution for this issue?

Really need someone to help me out, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having same problem in my project. it is working fine on android version 4.0.3 but not working on 4.1 and 4.2.2
   I searched a lot on internet and find the problem is in new android platform not in pouchdb. If u really want to work on local storage just use the IndexedDB

See this link https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/issues/504